# accessing array elements passed to php from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to access the serialized data in the var param that is sent to the admin_comment.php file. I feel like making a rookie mistake. Below is my jQuery code...

```
$(buildFormName).submit(function(e){


var param = $(e.target).serialize();

param = param + '&new_cid=' + theCommentId;

alert(param);

// params return as expected - look good

$.post('submit/admin_comment.php',param,function(msg){



});
});
```

In the admin_comment.php file I have this:

```
$arr = array();
```

And I'm trying to access an individual element of the array, `new_cid` like this:

```
$arr['new_cid'];
```

but it comes up empty... can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can change the $(e.target).serialize(); to $(this).serialize()

Answer (score 3):

The special array you're looking for is the PHP superglobal `$_POST`.

You should be able to get your data via:

```
$_POST['new_cid']
```

Comment: oh wow. amazing that i missed that one... everything works now - thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Welcome to PHP programming.